# ANOVA with groups having different sample sizes

Tags: anova, sample-size, sample

I have 3 groups

Group 1 with sample size ($n_1$) = 54 
Group 2 with sample size ($n_2$)= 87 
Group 3 with sample size ($n_3$) = 409

Can I carry one way group ANOVA? 
Also, can I include this variable in the factorial ANOVA?

Comment: It depends how well the assumptions of 1-way ANOVA are fulfilled (e.g. equal variance; random sampling). Equal sample size is not amongst them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can include this in a oneway or factorial ANOVA. There is no requirement that groups have the same size.

Answer (score 1):

ANOVA does not require equal sample sizes. So, there is nothing in what you have posted that prevents you from doing either a one way or factorial ANOVA.

Of course, you still have to check all the other assumptions.